Trigger on ContentVersion to Capture Enhanced Note content
I have been struggling to get an after insert trigger working on the ContentVersion object. The goal is to take the note content entered and populate a custom text field on the linked entity (related custom object). I found some code on this site in a similar question and adapted it for my purposes :-).
Please consider the following code:
   for(ContentVersion cv : [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id in : trigger.newMap.keySet() and IsLatest = true and FileType = 'SNOTE']) {

    for(ContentDocumentLink l : [SELECT LinkedEntityId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocumentId =: cv.ContentDocumentId and LinkedEntityId != null]) {

        if(string.valueOf(l.LinkedEntityId).left(3) == ConPrefix) {

            linkedEntityMap.put(cv.ContentDocumentId, l.LinkedEntityId);

        ContentDocIds.add(cv.ContentDocumentId);
        system.debug(cv.contentDocumentId);

        }

    }

}

I use this nested for loop for ContentVersion and ContentDocumentLink objects to create a map of Ids to create a 1:1 match traversing the object relationships. But when I use the debug log to determine what record Ids are being queried I notice that two separate ContentDocumentLink records are being found 1 for my user and 1 for the custom object of interest. And the ContentDocumentLink query only seems to grab the user related record and because I have the if statement that checks the record id prefix defined earlier in the trigger it of course ignores those records and ends up not updating the custom field. I get an error when I try to modify the query within the ContentDocumentLink for loop to filter for only the custom object linked record (ShareType = 'V') then I get a compile error:
[SELECT LinkedEntityId, ShareType FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocumentId =: cv.ContentDocumentId and ShareType = 'V' and LinkedEntityId != null]

Compile Error: Implementation restriction: filtering on non-id fields is only permitted when filtering by ContentDocumentLink.LinkedEntityId using the equals operator.
I could use some guidance here on how to isolate the desired ContentDocumentLink record.


ContentDocumentLink will always have a ContentDocumentId and a LinkedEntityId as it is a junction object; 2) ContentDocumentLink won't be populated until after the ContentVersion is inserted (because insert of a ContentVersion implicitly creates a ContentDocument (required for a ContentDocumentLink; 3) I find that writing the trigger on ContentDocumentLink to be more effective (at dealing with these order dependencies.  Use the debug log to understnad the sequence of DML operations (create a dummy trigger on CDL so you can expose values of the dml operation

